# Best way to handle sorting a huge 10 column table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So basically I have this huge list of items and I wanted to put it into a dynamic table. When a table header is clicked, my handleSort function is called. The target of the click also passes an argument to my handleSort function that tells it what header was clicked. My application does exactly what I want it to, the only issue is that I know this a super clunky way of accomplishing what I need. Below is my state and my handleSort function:

```
class ChampionsOverview extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      champions: [],
      updated: false,
      loading: true,
      currentSort: 'costAscending',
      name: '',
      traits: '',
      cost: ' ascending',
      health: '',
      armor: '',
      magicResist: '',
      dps: '',
      attackDamage: '',
      attackSpeed: '',
      range: ''
    }
    this.handleSort = this.handleSort.bind(this);
  }

  handleSort(event, header){
    switch(header) {
      case 'name':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'nameAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'nameDescending', name: ' descending', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'nameAscending', name: ' ascending', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'traits':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'traitsAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'traitsDescending', name: '', traits: ' descending', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'traitsAscending', name: '', traits: ' ascending', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'cost':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'costAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'costDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: ' descending', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'costAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: ' ascending', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'health':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'healthAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'healthDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: ' descending', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'healthAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: ' ascending', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'armor':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'armorAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'armorDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: ' descending', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'armorAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: ' ascending', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'magicResist':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'magicResistAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'magicResistDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: ' descending', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'magicResistAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: ' ascending', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'dps':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'dpsAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'dpsDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: ' descending', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'dpsAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: ' ascending', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'attackDamage':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'attackDamageAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'attackDamageDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: ' descending', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'attackDamageAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: ' ascending', attackSpeed: '', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'attackSpeed':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'attackSpeedAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'attackSpeedDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: ' descending', range: '' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'attackSpeedAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: ' ascending', range: '' }));
        break;
      case 'range':
        (this.state.currentSort === 'rangeAscending' ? this.setState({ currentSort: 'rangeDescending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: ' descending' }) : this.setState({ currentSort: 'rangeAscending', name: '', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: ' ascending' }));
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({ currentSort: 'costAscending', cost: ' ascending' });
    }
  }
```

Basically, I take the header that my event passed to me, and determine what the currentSort should be. If it is the same header that is currently active, I instead reverse the currentSort.

currentSort determines the order of my items, while the other states such as name, cost, and health determine icons that appear next to the table headers.

Any advice on how to clean up my code is 100% appreciated. This jumbled mess is killing me.

Update 1

```
<th id='ChampionOverviewMobile-table-header-row-name' className='ChampionOverviewMobile-table-header-row-item' onClick={event => this.handleSort(event, 'name')}>Name&nbsp;<Icon name={`sort${this.state.name}`}/></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make a couple optimizations. First, you don't need to specific each state prop when you set state. For example, instead of this:

```
this.setState({ currentSort: 'nameDescending', name: ' descending', traits: '', cost: '', health: '', armor: '', magicResist: '', dps: '', attackDamage: '', attackSpeed: '', range: '' });
```

You can just do this:

```
this.setState({ currentSort: 'nameDescending', name: ' descending' }));
```

The next optimization is it appears you have redundant information in state. Why have both `currentSort` equal to `nameDescending` and also `name` equal to `descending`? Instead, what if you just had a `direction` key and a `currentSort` key? Then, your `handleSort` function could greatly simplify:

```
handleSort(event, header) {
  const direction = header === this.state.currentSort ?
    this.state.direction * -1 : 1
  this.setState({  currentSort: header, direction });
}
```

Now, `this.state.direction` will be `1` for ascending or `-1` for descending. `this.state.currentSort` will tell you which column to sort.

**Icon Name**

Rather than storing the icon name redundantly in state, you can derive it in your `render` method. For example:

```
render() {
  const direction = this.state.direction === 1 ? "Ascending" : "Descending";
  const iconName = this.state.currentSort + direction;
  return <Icon name={`sort${iconName}`} />
}
```

Comment: The reason that I have name equal to descending was because of arrows that indicate to the user which sorting order is being used.

I have updated my original post ^
The name prop for the icon is an arrow that can be either ascending or descending.

Comment: You can derive that name from state rather than storing it redundantly. Let me update my answer real quick

Comment: Okay, I have updated showing how it works. Let me know what you think!

Comment: I like this a lot. I'm going to try it out with my application and I'll let you know how it goes! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, feel free to follow-up here if it's not working out

Comment: It went perfectly! My total lines of code for this feature went from 406 to 260! You rock!

Comment: Awesome! So glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using something like this:

```
handleSort(event, header) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    let propToClear;
    const entry = Object.entries(prevState).find(([key, value]) => ([' ascending', ' descending'].includes(value)));
    if (entry) {
      propToClear = entry[0];
    }

    const newState = {};
    if (propToClear) {
      newState[propToClear] = '';
    }

    let direction = 'ascending';
    if (propToClear == header && entry[1] == ' ascending') {
      direction = 'descending';
    }

    newState.currentSort = header + direction.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + direction.slice(1);
    newState[header] = ` ${direction}`;

    return newState;
  });
}
```

First part check the state to find the previous property that is set to `ascending` or `descending`, then check if the previous prop is the same as the current one to determine the direction and then clears the previous prop, sets the new prop and the value of `currentSort`.